# jquery replace images for responsive layout

Tags: jquery

In my HTML page, i have 3 images for each sizes, to match responsive layouts. on click how can i replace the name alone in the img?

example:

```
 <img class="img-1024" src="images/photo-holder.jpg" />
 <img class="img-768" src="images/768/photo-holder.jpg" />
 <img class="img-320" src="images/320/photo-holder.jpg" />
```

how to change like this?

```
 <img class="img-1024" src="images/new-holder.jpg" />
 <img class="img-768" src="images/768/new-holder.jpg" />
 <img class="img-320" src="images/320/new-holder.jpg" />
```

any shortest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One *short* option is using `attr` method.

```
$('img').attr('src', function(i, c) {
    return c.replace('photo', 'new')
});
```

or:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    this.src = this.src.replace('photo', 'new')
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hHSQe/

Answer (score 1):

Do this way:-

```
$(document).on("click", "img", function(){
    $(this).attr("src", function(i,v) { 
        return v.replace("photo","new");
    });
});​​
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/847sb/)**